# Draggable Script and Context Menu Conflict

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, draggable, conflict

I've downloaded and implemented a contextual menu js script and it is working quite well, except for one hang up. It interferes with a draggable script that i also have on the page, the draggable and contextual menu scripts operate on the same element(s).

What happens is that when i click the element to drag it, it refuses to release the element from the drag operation, so it just follows my cursor forever. This doesn't happen when the contextual menu script isn't linked to the html. So i assume something regarding mouse co-ordinates is the culprit, as both scripts deal with that.

Comment: There might be an accidental duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788566/jquery-context-menu-clashes-with-jquery-draggable