# Click on a draggable initiates dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-draggable

I have a tree structured `ul li` element in a page. I made the Leaf `li` to be draggable. We can drag and drop these `li` between their immediate parent `li`.

Everything going fine except one problem. If we click on the `li`, It started dragging and required another click to stop.

Just for information, We are using jquery treeview plugin to make this `ul li` structure a treeview.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any option in jquery treeview for this ?

Comment: The [treeview plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/), we are using is old one and lacks documentation.
It may have drag and drop feature but I have not found any example or documentation on that. So I implemented using jquery draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we  had a similar kind of issue due to the clash of Jquery Context Menu and draggable.

Update below code in jquery Context menu script file.

Ref : [jQuery Context Menu clashes with jQuery Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788566/jquery-context-menu-clashes-with-jquery-draggable) for more info.

```
jQuery(this).mousedown( function(e) {
var evt = e;
if (e.button == 2) //Added to make this compatible with draggable
    evt.stopPropagation();
jQuery(this).mouseup( function(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) //Added to make this compatible with draggable
        e.stopPropagation();
    var srcElement = jQuery(this);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Delay option when initializing the Draggable plugin. Setting this to 250 ms or something will delay the dragging so that if the user just clicks on the element it won't start dragging.

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-delay

Comment: I have tried with that approach. But it did not work.
When I put more delay like 2000ms. After I clicked on `li` element, It just staging draging after 2 sec.